# The complexity of bubble sort and insertion sort for a list with a given number of inversions

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, bubble-sort, insertion-sort

Let the length of a list be n, and the number of inversions be d. Why does insertion sort run in O(n+d) time and why does bubble sort not?

When I consider this problem I am thinking of the worst case scenario. Since the worse case for inversions is n(n-1)\2, both bubble and insertion sort run in the same time. But then I don't know how to answer the question since I find them the same. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bubble sort, if the last element needs to get to the first position (n inversions) you need to loop over the entire array n times, each time moving the element one position forward so you get n^2 steps, so you get O(N^2) regardless of the value of d.

The same setup in insertion sort will do only n+n steps to get everything sorted (O(N+d)). d is actually the total number of swaps insertion sort will need to do to get the thing sorted.

You went wrong when you assumed the worst case value of d is n(n-1)/2. While this is true, if you want to express the complexity in terms of d you can't replace it with it's worst value case, unless you're ok with a higher bound.

Comment: Could you please explain how you get O(N^2) regardless of the value of d for bubble sort? Why is d not relevant in the process? Since you don't do a swap when there is not an inversion, wouldn't the time it takes be related to d?

Comment: Take something like `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]` after you run once through the list you swap 9 and 1. After another run through the entrie list you swap 8 and 1 so you need N - 1 runs through the list, checking every consecutive elements each time, to get 1 to the first position. So in total you will do N* (N-1) comparisons. Yes, I think you will do d swaps in total but you still do N^2 comparisons and that gives you the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: In general you care about the number of steps an algorithm takes. How long each step takes is not relevant for complexity (but it does change the run-time). If your algorithm does N^2 checks and then takes a single step to generate the solution, the complexity is still O(N^2). If the algorithm does one check and N^2 steps to generate the solution, the complexity is still O(N^2).